# WSO2 ESB "Sending a simple message" tutorial gives server port is already in use

Tags: wso2-esb

I have been following the following tutorial

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sending+a+Simple+Message+Through+the+ESB

however, when I get to the section "To add WSO2 ESB as a server in Developer Studio" and specifically step 6 I get the error "Starting WSO2 Carbon 4.4 based server at localhost has encountered a problem.  Server port is in use: 9443."

Since this is an introductory tutorial I am struggling to understand the problem.  I could try different ports but worry I'm not understanding something although I have checked every step.

Have you run this tutorial successfully and how did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you already have a running ESB or any WSO2 Product. Normally this issue comes if you try to run multiple Products at the same time. kill all java/wso2 processors and retry.

Suggestion :  use command line interface to start the server.

goto bin folder of wso2 esb and type the command wso2server.bat.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when going through the initial steps of WS02, one would have started the EI or the ESB. Go back to command prompt and close the existing connection. Then come back to the tutorial and start the server. It will now start the server and the sample app will be available for testing